# Sum formula monthly columns

Tags: excel, sum, forecast

im trying to sum up a group of monthly figures into my summary page from other tabs, without using SUM formula, as the other tabs column shifts and moves everytime its copied over.

im trying to find a formula that captures the total of the year, even though the columns move.

below is the tab[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfvRx.png)

trying to get the summary like the below [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCCKs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the column number of your total with `match` formula.  Then get the sum with `vlookup` like this:

[image]